# Member selector expression combining two classes

Tags: c#, inheritance, multiple-inheritance, expression-trees

I have two classes (or models rather) having some common properties. For instance:

```
public class Model1
{
    public int Common1 { get; set; }
    public int Common2 { get; set; }
    public int Prop11 { get; set; }
    public int Prop12 { get; set; }
}

public class Model2
{
    public int Common1 { get; set; }
    public int Common2 { get; set; }
    public int Prop21 { get; set; }
    public int Prop22 { get; set; }
}
```

I need to write a method that can accept a member selector expression where the member to select can come from either of the two models. This is what I mean:

```
public List<T> GetAnon<T>(Expression<Func<??, T>> selector) // <-- intriguing part
{
    // codes to extract property names from selector and create the return object of type T
}

// And this is an example usage of the method
// At this point, I don't know which model Common1, Prop11 or Prop21 belongs to
var anonObj = GetAnon(m => new { m.Common1, m.Prop11, m.Prop21 });
// anonObj = { Common1 = VALUE_1, Prop11 = VALUE_2, Prop21 = VALUE_3 }
```

Please note that the `selector` passed selects both from `Model1` and also from `Model2`.

**My current solution:** Create a model with the common properties, say `Model`, have `Model1` and `Model2` inherit `Model` with the rest of the properties in the individual models. Then make another model, say `TempModel`, that inherits `Model`, and add the non-common properties to it. Like so:

```
public class Model
{
    public int Common1 { get; set; }
    public int Common2 { get; set; }
}

public class Model1 : Model
{
    public int Prop11 { get; set; }
    public int Prop12 { get; set; }
}

public class Model2
{
    public int Prop21 { get; set; }
    public int Prop22 { get; set; }
}

public class TempModel : Model
{
    public int Prop11 { get; set; }
    public int Prop12 { get; set; }
    public int Prop21 { get; set; }
    public int Prop22 { get; set; }
}

// Finally, first type parameter can be TempModel
public List<T> GetAnon<T>(Expression<Func<TempModel, T>> selector)
{
    // codes to extract property names from selector and create the return object of type T
}
```

The problem with this approach is that if `Model1` and `Model2` change, which they are prone to, I will have to remember to make the changes to `TempModel` as well, which is something I would like to avoid. Also, I would like to avoid passing the names of the properties as strings, so that I do not lose intellisense.

How can I achieve this? Obviously, multiple-inheritance is not possible in C#, otherwise my problem would have become trivial.

**Edit:**

I have edited my question to reflect my actual need (though I am not sure if that really helps). I actually need to create and return an object of anonymous type `T` inside the method `GetAnon()`. To create the object I need the names of the properties so that I can perform the retrieval (using SQL). I don't want to lose intellisence by passing names as strings. Also, at the point of calling the method, I do not know which property comes from which model, all I know are the property names.

Comment: Why do you need a list of the member names? Would it help to use interfaces (which do support multiple inhertance)?

Comment: @Adrian That's a good idea, and I've thought of it too. I am afraid it wouldn't help, because the classes are actually _models_. Also, I am not _allowed_ in the project I am working on to change these models into interfaces. Now, regarding your question why I need the names, should I edit the question and add the details, but somehow I don't think that would help much.

Comment: Maybe just pass Expression<Func<Model1,Model2, T>> selector?

Comment: @Evk That's a good idea, but like I said in comment in Ron's answer, I don't know which property comes from which model at the place of calling it. But still, I think this a nice solution after all.

Comment: Then I don't really understand what you are trying to do. I mean I don't see what you can do with your `TempModel` approach which you cannot do with my approach. Your `GetMemberNames(x => x.Common1)` is mine `GetMemberNames((m1,m2) => m1.Common1)` (or `m2.Common1`, doesn't matter), and so on.

Comment: @Evk Yeah, my intent is somewhat hazy I agree. In your approach, which I agree is great, while calling the method if I don't find a property in `m1`, then I will have to try with `m2`. That's the only difference I can think of. But I wonder if there is any other way. BTW, you should add your approach as an answer. ;-)

Comment: @Evk Sorry to break your peace :P, but are you going to add your approach as an answer? I shall accept your answer if you add one, for I ended up following that approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the all around easiest way would be to just use:

```
public List<T> GetAnon<T>(Expression<Func<Model1, Model2, T>> selector) {

}
```

It might be a little bit inconvenient for the caller, because he has to remember (or figure it out by trial and error) which model has property he needs, but I think inconvenience is minor and benefit is big enough (no need for additional classes, which as you said are error-prone to maintain).

Usage will be:

```
var propNames = GetAnon((m1, m2) => new { m1.Common1, m1.Prop11, m2.Prop21 });
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you may be over-complicating the use of the selector function. I'm assuming you want to use a lambda there because you don't want to have to worry about changing the property name in a string if you change it in your model. That is exactly what the `nameof` function was designed for.

```
public List<string> GetMemberNames<T1, T2>(IEnumerable<string> propNames)
{
    var commonProps = (from pn in propNames
                       where
                       typeof(T1).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public)
                                 .Any(p => p.Name == pn) ||
                       typeof(T2).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public)
                                 .Any(p => p.Name == pn)
                       select pn).ToList();

    return commonProps;
}
```

Usage:

```
var cp = GetMemberNames<Model1, Model2>(new[] 
                        { nameof(Model1.Common1),   
                          nameof(Model2.Common2), 
                          nameof(Model1.Prop11), 
                          nameof(Model2.Prop21),
                          "SomeUnknownProperty", 
                        });
```

Notice now you don't need to have an instance of either model to obtain the list of property names.

Result:

[image]

Comment: That's indeed quite a good way, +1, but the problem is one _can_ pass some arbitrary string and break it. That is also something I would like to avoid. Also, while invoking the method, I only know the property names, but don't know which property comes from which model.

Comment: @Sнаđошƒаӽ I'm not sure how it would break it, I show an "arbitrary" string in the example and it handles it quite well. You don't have to use `nameof`, but I'm not entirely sure how you know the property names but not where they came from?

Comment: How it would break it - I have some other tasks to perform using the property names, and if either of the models do not contain any of the property passed, it would break the subsequent codes. How I don't know where they come from - I am afraid you just have to trust me. I am converting some delphi to C#, and the original source is that *hitty delphi codes.